# Wait until the text-field values are fetched through API in Watir-WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I am writing the registration script where the API is being called in company registration no field and it fetches all the data regarding company and fill it automatically in according field like name, phone no, address etc. So i want to make the script wait until all text-fields are filled with values. I have tried the following script but it doesn't wait and clicks on continue button before all the values are fetched.

```
require "watir-webdriver"
require "watir-webdriver/wait"

br = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
br.goto verification_link

br.a(:text => "Continue Manually").flash
br.a(:text => "Continue Manually").click
br.text_field(:id => "regNumber").flash
br.text_field(:id => "regNumber").set "03977902"
br.button(:id => "populatebtn").flash
br.button(:id => "populatebtn").click

Watir::Wait.until(10) {br.text_field(:id => "companyName").value.exists?}

br.select_list(:id => "companyType").flash
br.select_list(:id => "companyType").select("Limited")
br.select_list(:id => "nature").flash
br.select_list(:id => "nature").select("Art")
br.text_field(:id => "sales_turnover").flash
br.text_field(:id => "sales_turnover").set "12000"
br.select_list(:id => "why").flash
br.select_list(:id => "why").select("Bill Payment")
br.button(:id => "lookup").flash
br.button(:id => "lookup").click
br.button(:id => "continue").flash
br.button(:id => "continue").click
```

Comment: There are a couple of answers to this question (including one from me) here https://groups.google.com/d/topic/watir-general/CVE4yznlYcs/discussion

Answer (score 1):

Maulik,

Instead of waiting until a value exists, how about trying something along the following lines:

```
br.wait_until{br.text_field(:id=> 'companyName').text.eql?("") == false}
```